# Getting issue while comparing one property to another in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

In my JMeter test plan, I want to set a flag in case of failure in every HTTP request. So I created a JSR223 PostProcessor in request with the following snippet:

```
if (!prev.isSuccessful()) {
    int abc = 1 
    props.put('result', vars.get('abc'))
    
}
```

where result is defined as global in the thread.

In teardown I want to exit JMeter by comparing with the value of the flag . So I am doing the following:

```
if ((props.get('result') as int) == 1) {
    System.exit(1);
}
```

Can anyone help me what wrong I am doing in this? Is there any other way by which I can do this.

Answer (score 1):

This statement `vars.get('abc')` will return `null` because you just declare an integer called `abc` and not writing it to JMeter Variables.

You need to amend your code to something like:

```
if (!prev.isSuccessful()) {
    int abc = 1 
    props.put('result', abc)

}
```

also there is no need to cast it to the integer back, it's stored as the object of the given type

```
if (props.get('result')  == 1) {
    System.exit(1);
}
```

More information:

- [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) aka `props`
- [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) aka vars
- [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes)

You may also find [AutoStop Listener](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/AutoStop/) useful